# Convert a String to an Activity class

Tags: java, android, string, class, android-activity

I am trying to create an `Activity` class from a string and pass it to a static method. I found this on SO to pass a string into a class. `FirstActivity` is already created.

SecondActivity

```
String myClass = "com.package.FirstActivity";
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(myClass);
//this works
//Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myClass);
//I want to pass to a static method, but it gives a error. Class cannot cast to Activity
StaticMethod.processThis(myClass , "test");
```

StaticMethod

```
public static void processThis(Activity contextActivity, String str) {
     //do processing
}
```

How can I get `processThis` to work? If I understand correctly, an `Activity` is also a class?

Comment: Exactly what is your problem? Do you want to solve a certain problem in your application or want to make work the above code?

Comment: I want to get my `processThis` method working. Made my question clearer.

Comment: How do I cast? I tried `Activity newActivity = (Activity) myClass`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of FirstActivity. If this class has a constructor with no-aruments you can do the following:

```
String myClass = "com.package.FirstActivity";
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(myClass);
Activity obj = (Activity) myClass.newInstance();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myClass); //Maybe here also obj must be needed

//Noe pass your object here
StaticMethod.processThis(obj, "test");
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I am looking for. I couldnt find a way to cast the class to activity.

Comment: But don't even think to change your structure afterwards :-/